# Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$

**here's first attempt**

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{(n+1)!}&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n-1}{(n)!}\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1-n}{(n)!}\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{(n)!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{n}{(n)!}
\end{eqnarray}
By $$e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n!}x^n$$we have
$$e^{-1}-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{(n)!}$$
so we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=2e^{-1}-1$$

What are other possible approaches?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{e^x -1}{x}=\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!} $$
Differentiate:

$$\frac{xe^x -(e^x-1)}{x^2}=\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Set $x=-1$:

$$1-2e^{-1} = \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} n}{(n+1)!} $$

Multiply both sides by $-1$:

$$2e^{-1}-1 =\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n n}{(n+1)!} $$

Answer (score 1):

Almots the same as you did, maybe a bit clearer.

We have $\frac{n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot (1-\frac{1}{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.

So
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} - 1 + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} -1+1$$
$$=2e^{-1} -1$$